# Make variable available in template file

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am creating a custom template file for a views table and I need to put some links in the footer of the table, these links belong to 3 nodes. How can I make this data available in my template file which is - views-view-table--my-view-name.html.twig

Is there a pre-process of some sort that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can override `template_preprocess_views_view_table()` in your own `THEMENAME.theme` file

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables){
   $variables['node1'] = "value from node 1";
}
```

in your twig file you should have the variable available

```
{{node1}}
```